# Рефакторинг кода с#

Tags: c#, .net, рефакторинг

Подскажите пожалуйста сервисы для онлайн рефакторинга кода на c# и да вообще такие есть??

Comment: для рефакторинга используют голову, а не сервисы. Также в студии есть встроенные возможности рефакторингов, наподобие переименовать метод или превратить поле в свойство.

Comment: ReSharper и сама студия - самые лучшие вещи для рефакторинга...

Answer (score 4):

Лучший инструмент -- это голова. Для лучшей работы этого инструмента помогут следующие книги:

- "Совершенный код", МакКоннелл
- "Чистый код", Мартин
- "Рефакторинг", Фаулер

А упомянутые IDE, Решарперы и гипотетические онлайн-сервисы -- не более чем полезное дополнение. Что-то за вас они могут оптимизировать (например, подскажут вынести сложное условие в отдельный метод), но это все поверхностно. Потому как рефакторинг бывает разного уровня -- от кода до архитектуры.

Comment: я бы еще добавил С. Тепляков "Паттерны проектирования"